# JQuery, Ajax and PHP : Sending FormData AND String values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'd like to send to a PHP page a FormData value and some String values.

**Here's my code on the JS side:**

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'upload-pic.php', 
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                type : type,
                id : id,
                formData : formData
            },
            processData:false,
            success: function(data, status) {

                //stuff i'm doing with the data 

            }
        });
```

**And on the PHP side :**

```
if(isset($_POST['type']) && isset($_POST['id'])){
    //stuff i'm doing
}
```

Then, I get an error saying that type and id are not set. I'm guessing that this comes from the **processData: false** from my ajax call. 
But without this, I get the inevitable Illegal Invocation, coming from trying to send the FormData.

Is there any way to send the FormData AND my String values on the same call ?

Thanks!

Comment: we need more code - your values "type" and "id" are not set in your example and thats why you receive your error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object, in that case you need to append the string values to the `FormData` object, and pass the object in as the `data` parameter in `jQuery's` `$.ajax`.

You can append data to the `FormData` object, with the method `append`.

This should work:

```
formData.append('type', type);
fromData.append('id', id);
$.ajax({
    url: 'upload-pic.php', 
    type: 'post',
    data: formData,
    processData:false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data, status) {
         //stuff i'm doing with the data 
    }
});
```